# Jq substract 2 keys and add it to json

Tags: linux, json, jq

I have a json like this one

```
{
  "status": "InProgress",
  "transactionId": "1652807586",
  "startTime": "2022-05-17T17:13:06Z",
  "viewIdContexts": {
    "dtve2.2": {
      "subgraphStatusCounts": {
        "end": 10,
        "start": 4,
        "startReturned": 127
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to subtract end and start and add it to json so the expected result is

```
{
  "status": "InProgress",
  "transactionId": "1652807586",
  "startTime": "2022-05-17T17:13:06Z",
  "viewIdContexts": {
    "dtve2.2": {
      "subgraphStatusCounts": {
        "end": 10,
        "start": 4,
        "result": 6,
        "startReturned": 127
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How this can be achieved in jq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```bsh
jq '.result = .end - .start'
```

This reads the input JSON document and sets the top-level `result` key to the result of the subtraction of `start` from `end`.

Example run:

```bsh
$ echo '{ "end": 10, "start": 4 }' | jq '.result = .end - .start'
{
  "end": 10,
  "start": 4,
  "result": 6
}
```

Use `jq` with its `-c` option to get "compact" output.

---

With the JSON document in the updated question, pick out the relevant part and update it (`|=`) with the result:

```bsh
jq '.viewIdContexts."dtve2.2".subgraphStatusCounts |= (.result = .end - .start)'
```

Note that one of the keys needs to be quoted as it contains a dot.

The first command in this answer is a simplification of

```bsh
jq '. |= (.result = .end - .start)'
```

which should show how it's similar to the longer command in this part of the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. What if the json is a nested structure like the following  `  {
  "status": "InProgress",
  "transactionId": "1652807586",
  "startTime": "2022-05-17T17:13:06Z",
  "viewIdContexts": {
    "dtve2.2": {
      "subgraphStatusCounts": {
        "end": 14702,
        "start": 26379,
        "startReturned": 127
      }
    }
  }
} `

Comment: @SanchuVarkey If you have clarifications to your question, then please update the question.

Comment: Hi @Kusalananda I have updated the question now

Comment: @SanchuVarkey See added bit to the answer.

Comment: Perfect thank you. I was missing the bracket part. Thank you again

Comment: Last question if the start is missing, can we treat that as 0?

Comment: @SanchuVarkey Use `(.start // 0)` in place of `.start` to default to zero if the value is null or missing.

Comment: Thank you. I hope this is useful for others in the future.